Windows not booting after cleaning old drive
I recently added a new ssd to my laptop and cloned my old drive to the new one using macrium reflect. Then I set the new drive to boot first in bios settings. After that I clean the old drive using diskpart. Now windows is not booting up from the second/new drive. I even tried booting up from the new drive from one time boot menu but did not work.
Note: I did not switch drives on my machine after cloning. They are each in their respective slots as before cloning.

Did you cloned the whole drive including the ESP?

Efi system partition? If so, i did it. I cloned the entire disk, all partitions

There are many questions on this site regarding issues booting Windows after a drive upgrade. I recommend looking through these for the windows 10 and 11 specific questions and reviewing the answers on them: https://superuser.com/search?q=windows+boot+after+drive

My pc was working before cleaning the old drive, even if it was not used. After my pc just refused to boot up even if I cloned every thing, even the windows boot manager from the old drive to the new one. Before cleaning I just set the boot sequence to the wiindows boot manager present on the second drive.
